# Join table not being created when adding a list of IdentityUser to an entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two different types of users that have different properties so I created 2 new classes and each of them inherit from `AppUser`. I am aware that EF uses a discriminator column in the `AspNetUsers` table when doing this. Additionally, a student has many teachers so I expect a join table to be created that will have `TeacherUserId` and `StudentId`.

When I run `Update-Database`, it adds a `StudentId` column to the `AspNetUsers` table.

Where is my `StudentTeachers` table? It seems like it is trying to handle it in `AspNetUsers` table with many rows which would be horrible. I don't want to create a new identity user for every single `student.teacher`.

Here are my model classes:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherUser : AppUser
{
    public string TeacherSpecificProperty { get; set };
}

public class StudentUser : AppUser
{
    public string StudentSpecificProperty { get; set };
}

public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Teachers= new List<TeacherUser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<TeacherUser> Teachers{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: EF Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many): *"Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships."*

Comment: @IvanStoev So I would create a class called StudentTeacher with two properties in it: Student and TeacherUser. Will I need to specify anything additional in fluent api? Also, I will need to add DbSet<StudentTeacher> to my context and when seeding the database I will need to manually create the StudentTeachers correct?

Comment: Basically yes. All this is the example from the link.